# Why does Windows Forms Designer resize my controls?

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple button. Whenever I change its width the designer automatically updates the height and even updates the width to a different value.

The only way around this I found is to set min and max size to the same value.

For whatever reason when I set width to 30 it turns out as 38. What is causing this?

AutoSize is false.

[image]

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: Check the Anchor Property..

Comment: You don't have a *simple Button*, that Control sports properties that don't belong to a standard Button